# Data CD recognized as blank

Tags: windows-7, dvd, compact-disc

I understand this question has been asked multiple times. But in most of those cases, it would apply to all CDs or all DVDs which is not the case in my scenario.

My DVD Drive is TSSTCorp TS-L633C AS01 and I am using ASUS Laptop. The thing is, the drive has no problems reading DVDs. However, in case of CDs, it is being picky. Some of my CDs are being read fine and some of them aren't. The CDs themselves have no scratches or smudges on them. I see this issue on Windows 7 as well as on Ubuntu 14.04. I hadn't used my DVD drive for a while. I tried cleaning the lens with a clean dry cloth too. I know my last option is to replace the drive. But just want to make sure if there is anything else I can do from my end.

Comment: You will need to verify the disk can be read on another machine before we can help.

Comment: @Ramhound: They can be read. Verified.